# Selecting the TypeName of an Object in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am working on putting together a report for monitoring the ACLs for a series of data shares and when I run my script I get the results seen below in my screenshot.  As you can see, `Path: \\rest_of_path` is displayed above each object.

This looks like when I use `Get-Member`, `TypeName:` is shown in that position.  I want to be able to take that `Path` value and add it to my report so that I can produce something that looks like the output within the PowerShell console.  How can I do that?

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the code: (I'm using the NTFSSecurity module as seen here, https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/11/23/weekend-scripter-manage-ntfs-inheritance-and-use-privileges/)

```
import-module -Name \\storagesrvr\it\!scripts\ntfssecurity -verbose

$shares = get-content \\testserver\c$\tmp\share.list.txt

$results = @()

foreach($share in $shares){
    $ntfs = Get-NTFSAccess $share
    $results += $ntfs
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and share a code snippet producing above output. Read and follow how-to create a [mcve]. Use fake values for private data, of course.

Comment: @BenH Thanks for the reply.  But, when I try that, I don't get the path name, just "Security2.FileSystemAccessRule2".

Comment: @BenH I'm sorry for the confusion.  I edited the original post.  However, I tried the Select Path already and it returns no results.

Comment: @BenH Another edit added to the original post.

Comment: `$results | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `Path` is the formatted combination from `FullName` and `InheritanceEnabled`

```
$results | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Select-Object @{
        Name="Path"
        Expression={"$($_.Fullname) $(if(!($_.InheritanceEnabled)) {'(Inheritance Disabled)'})"}
    }
}
```

Or to put that calculated property directly into `$results`

```
import-module -Name \\storagesrvr\it\!scripts\ntfssecurity -verbose
$shares = get-content \\testserver\c$\tmp\share.list.txt
$results = foreach($share in $shares){
    $ntfs = Get-NTFSAccess $share |
        select *,@{n="Path";e={"$($_.Fullname) $(if(($_.InheritanceEnabled)) {'(Inheritance Disabled)'})"}}
}
```